# How to iterate below json in grails gsp page to get each correspondance label and value

Tags: grails, groovy

[{"label":"AAA","value":0},{"label":"BBB","value":0},{"label":"CCC","value":0}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to **parse it** in the server-side:

```
// Parse the JSON
def list = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonString)
```

Then **send** it **to** your **gsp** and iterate as a regular map

```
<g:each in="${list}">
    <p>Label: ${it.label}</p>
    <p>Value: ${it.value}</p>
</g:each>
```

Comment: Actually i want to parse same stuff on gsp page itself. for the same string i don't want to take support from controller.e.g. def list = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonString)

Comment: is there a legit reason to not do it in controller? other than that - you can use javascript to parse and use it.

Comment: Not at all, finally i use above solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse like this your script.

```
var jsonString = [  
   {  
      "label":"AAA",
      "value":0
   },
   {  
      "label":"BBB",
      "value":0
   },
   {  
      "label":"CCC",
      "value":0
   }
];

$.each(jsonString, function(key, val) {
    console.log(val.label + ", " + val.value);
});
```

for demo please check this

http://jsfiddle.net/dipakthoke07/dfLFG/161/

Comment: If you wan to use script then its working fine.Thanks.